# Is it possible to create new C# scripts with proper namespace?

Tags: c#, godot

I'm using the C# Mono version for Godot and would like to know if it is possible to configure Godot to make use of namespaces. When creating a new script at

`./Folder/MyClass.cs`

I would expect the namespace to be

`MyProject.Folder`

So the created file should be similiar to

```
using Godot;

namespace MyProject.Folder
{
    public class MyClass : Node2D { }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @AkashKansara would you mind explaining where to find this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to configure Godot to do this. To be clear, it is possible to create custom templates for scripts, see [Creating script templates](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/creating_script_templates.html). However, as far as I can tell Godot does not offer a way to use the folder path (or its parts) in a template.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think its possible to do this full automatically.
But if you are using vs code you can just click on the class definition and press ctrl + point or press the lamp icon to show some quick options and than you can select the change namespace to MyProject.Folder option.

[image: like this example]